# clickhouse disk based dictionaries

Tags: clickhouse

Problem description:
I will have regular inserts into a table(lets call it 'daily'), I am planning to build a MV on top of this, I need data from another static table('metadata') .

Option 1: Do a join but that would load the 'metadata' table in memory

Option 2:
How do I limit dictionaries to be on disk and only 'X' bytes loaded in memory? 
The dictionary has 600 million rows and takes around 100 GB of memory, I am using low end machines and do not want to use so much RAM.
I am okay with latency.

How do I solve this, is there any setting ?

Comment: I would implement it on ETL stage, before CH.

Comment: And there are cached dictionaries https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/query_language/dicts/external_dicts_dict_layout/#cache

Comment: And `partial_merge_join=1` does merge JOIN with limited memory